# Inserting Relative formulas in array and then pasting the array to new sheet without @ symbol before the function name

Tags: arrays, excel

In my code i am trying to grab an array, change the values for certain columns in the array to change them to formulas, and then paste that array into a new sheet. I am having no issues when inserting simple formulas like 1+1 into the array, But when i use relative cell references like my "=Xlookup(RC[-11],'EXPD %'!A2:A100,'EXPD %'!B2:B100)" formula, the Pasting of those formulas includes an @ symbol before the xlookup and then i get a #Name? error in those cells. Is there a better way to do this in the array before pasting it into the new sheet? or is it a better option to paste the array and then do some sort of range().formula2

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = QNA.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
If arr(i, 4) = "NAGS" Then arr(i, 19) = "=1+1"
If arr(i, 4) = "EXPD" Then arr(i, 19) = "=Xlookup(RC[-11],'EXPD %'!A2:A100,'EXPD %'!B2:B100)"
If arr(i, 4) = "AMR1" Then arr(i, 19) = "=1+3"
If arr(i, 13) = "" Then arr(i, 13) = "=1+5"
If arr(i, 13) = 0 Then arr(i, 13) = "=1+5"
  
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
Next i

Dim RowC As Long, CoC As Long
RowC = UBound(arr, 1)
CoC = UBound(arr, 2)
WBNA.Range("a1").Resize(RowC, CoC).Value = arr
```

Comment: Side note, why are you mixing R1C1 and A1 notation in `"=Xlookup(RC[-11],'EXPD %'!A2:A100,'EXPD %'!B2:B100)"`? Also, what happens if you use `.Formula2` instead of `.Value`? (of course, after fixing the notation in the XLOOKUP).

Comment: The Lookup up array and return array are referencing a table on another worksheet in the  work book. I am using the R1C1 to reference a specific column to use as the lookup value and then searching that table on the EXPD % worksheet. I did try the .formla2 and it is now not including the @ symbol, but am now having other issues with those references to the other sheet.

Comment: You really shouldn't mix R1C1 and A1 notation though (asked [previously today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664835/vba-keeps-changing-the-formula-i-put-into-a-range)).

Comment: So i to reference my Table on the EXPD % sheet with the R1C1 notation? and if i am using that range for multiple formulas, i could make that a variable?